# uDeploy does not include all sub-folders (wildcard not working)

Tags: deployment, wildcard, udeploy

On my uDeploy process, I created .zip file step.
After downloading artifacts, I want uDeploy to zip all files under base directory.

Base directory structure:

```
archive
        sites
            bin
                *All binaries required*
```

Include option is set for **/* and I assume this wildcard should include all subdirectories to archive (.zip)

But after I run the process, I am getting following warning:

```
Working Directory: E:\CustomerFtp\Rel_1.0_20160418_122247\Artifacts
Base Directory: E:\CustomerFtp\Rel_1.0_20160418_122247\Artifacts\Archive
Zip file name: CustomerFtp.Archive.zip
Include: **/*
Exclude: 
Update : false
Follow Symlinks: false
Case Sensitive: false
=================================
[zip] Warning: skipping zip archive E:\CustomerFtp\Rel_1.0_20160418_122247\Artifacts\CustomerFtp.Archive.zip because no files were included.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is a sort of stupid, but even on Windows, looks like folder paths are case-sensitive for uDeploy.

So, I had to change folder name from **archive to Archive**, and problem get fixed.